# Aura error message on existing page even though we're not Lightning enabled

Tags: aura, salesforce-classic, winter18

Got a standard page layout in Classic with two chart controls on it.  Today it's rending the following error under the chart

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. [Assertion Failed!: AuraClientService.loadClientLibrary(): ClientLibrary has not been registered: eclairng : undefined]

but that's not a part of code we have.  Where do we begin to fix this?  Google not turning up anything for AuraClientService.loadClientLibrary

Comment: Just because you haven't enabled it, doesn't mean that Lightning isn't lurking in the background. Many of the pages and standard components have moved to Lightning in the past couple of years, and lots of new features use Lightning as well. However, not enabling Lightning shouldn't break the new features. You should probably contact Support.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox just checking if anyone else has seen and solved this before punting it to Support.  Will do that now.

Comment: For anyone else hitting this - happens when you add a Report Chart to a Standard Page Layout and only *seems* to affect Winter 18 instances when using Chrome.

Comment: If it's only Winter 18, and only Chrome, it's definitely a bug. Make sure you report it to Support, and insist that they log a bug.

Comment: Yup, all done, had a good chat with the agent who seemed very on the ball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is now confirmed as a bug by SFDC, putting this as the "answer" - they';ve been able to reproduce it in their own Winter 18 sandboxes under Chrome and confirm it doesn't occur in the preceding release.  Tracking numbers to follow when I have them

[UPDATE 18 Sep 2017] - Confirmed as a bug by Salesforce, ref. **[W-4317136](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCKtQAM&title=errors-seen-below-embedded-report-chart-in-winter-18)**

Comment: Can you [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/191835/edit) this answer to include more information, such as a tracking id or any statements given by support?